ASP.NET Core 8 simple app executes requests one by one
I've created a new ASP.NET Core 8 Web API from a template. I've added this simple route:
app.MapGet("/", async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(10_000);
    return Results.Ok("OK");
});

After the app is up, I already have 3 tabs in incognito mode opened and I go to my web address. It turned out that the queries to the app are being executed one by one: the first request is being executed 10 seconds, the second - ~19 seconds, the third - ~27 seconds.
I expected them all to be completed in about 10 seconds.
Why the app doesn't process the three query in parallel?

Can't reproduce.

How do you run your app? Debug/Release mode? IIS(Express)/standalone? Do you have breakpoints enabled? Do you have some extra setup code or this is only change compared to the template?

I might reproduce your issue, could you pls help confirm about the time cost in the browser console window? https://i.sstatic.net/JpOYmA52.png

Update, I had a test in an MVC application and an API application, they have the same result. When the requests are sending from the same browser, let's say I opened 2 private window in Chrome, and 1 private window in Edge, then call the api one by one, I will find the second request send in Chrome will cost some more time, while the another 2 requests will cost the same time. https://i.sstatic.net/8CwcAuTK.png

I have the same results in Chrome: 3 tabs, 1st takes 10s, 2dn takes 20s, 3rd takes 30s to load. However, in Firefox they all load at the same time (after 10 seconds)

In this link, there's an explanation for the stalled time. But I don't think my test scenario matches one of the reason. If you had the same issue with me, you might take a look at this section too.

Each of these phases may appear in the Timing tab:
Queueing. The browser queues requests when any of the following are true
There are higher priority requests.
There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache.
Stalled. The request could be stalled for any of the reasons described in Queueing.

The reason for this behavior is not in the application, but in the browser.
PS. Thanks to Tiny Wang for the clarification!
